# Automatic Downloads in Google Chrome

Tags: google, chrome

The questions I have relate to automatic downloads in Google Chrome, under Settings > Advanced > Content settings.

For starters, are there any security risks associated with allowing sites to ask when they want to download multiple files automatically to my computer after I decide to download the first file?

Can anyone here give an example of a legitimate website that does this?

This seems like something that could easily be abused by nefarious actors.

Is it really that hard to ask people to download multiple files separately, instead of allowing sites to download multiple files automatically after the first download, when downloading a program/file on the internet?

It seems like the trade off between a little bit of convenience gained and security doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: I've downloaded thousands of files at once, if i had to manually approve each one i would jump out the window. The context is a backup-enabling userscript that bulk downloaded student's pdf submissions to an LMS. The LMS didn't provide a way to download w/o clicking. A site _could_ bundle many downloads into a zip, and that's usually more convenient, but it does require a bit of extra coding and might not be feasible for all providers, compared to the simplicity of triggering many downloads from `<a download>` tags.

Comment: Part 1: Thank you dandavis for taking the time to respond to my question. Reading your comment, I get the impression that allowing or blocking sites to ask whether they can download multiple files, isn't really a security issue, because if a person is going to include malware in a zip archive, then it doesn't really matter whether the victim has set their browser to allow sites to ask whether the browser can download multiple files.

Comment: Part 2: Once the malicious actor is successful in tricking the user into downloading malware, it doesn't really matter whether the browser is allowed to download multiple files automatically, since a hacker could just as well include malware in a single file as he could multiple files. Is that correct? But then again this is a technical forum for security questions, so I could be wrong. Maybe blocking multiple downloads automatically would have the benefit of blocking most forms of malicious archives, since malware authors might have a tendency to split malicious code into multiple files?

Comment: Part 3: When we are talking about allowing Google Chrome to download multiple files automatically, are we essentially talking about zip archives? Or can Google Chrome download multiple files after a user has chosen to download the first file in a non-zip format?

Comment: it's more an an annoyance protection than a security measure. i think the approval to continue is needed for the 3rd or 4th file, which unlocks an unlimited number of downloads. the type or content (good or bad) of the file doesn't matter.

Comment: I still don't understand, though, how the downloading of multiple files automatically in Chrome works. Do these files need to be in a zip, or can Google Chrome download files on a website that are found in multiple locations, after you decide to download the first file? If the latter, then that sounds like allowing sites to download multiple files could enable drive-by downloads. Example: a user thinks he's downloading an innocuous .jpeg file, and he is, but as soon as the download finishes, the browser downloads an unsophisticated zero-day trojan that isn't detected by his anti-virus.

Comment: Since the trojan isn't picked up by his antivirus, the victim doesn't notice anything abnormal, and signs in to his banking account. His login credentials then get intercepted and sent to the attacker. If automatic downloads work in Chrome the same as the latter, then an attacker doesn't need to know of any vulnerability in Google Chrome. If he can trick the victim into downloading an innocuous .jpeg file, then he can then download a trojan onto the victim's computer once the browser is done downloading that .jpeg if the user has automatic downloads enabled.

Comment: This really isn't a security question. As dandavis points out any malware can be in the very first file downloaded so no point in attackers trying to abuse multi download functionality. As to how multiple download works, that is off topic here as well.